# Replace Character in Python Before Writing to File

Tags: python, string, forms, variables, replace

I need to create a CSV based on html form input. I have it working, but if someone puts a comma in one of the fields, then there will be an issue. This is very likely to happen due to the expected input. Is there a way to replace commas in the input string *before* it gets written to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to create CSV files with Python (including automatically dealing with this comma issue) is to use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) standard library module. You can use this by creating a CSV writer object with

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open(filename))
```

Then you can actually write to the file with [`writer.writerow`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) or [`writer.writerows`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)

If you want the columns in your file to be named, you can use a [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Answer (score 2):

Use `csv` module it will quote the commas for you:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerow(['field with comma ,, ..', '2nd field'])
"field with comma ,, ..",2nd field
```

To read it back:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> next(csv.reader(StringIO('"field with comma ,, ..",2nd field')))
['field with comma ,, ..', '2nd field']
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace the commas, the `csv` module will handle it for you. It will quote those fields that contain embedded commas. For example:

```
import csv
data = [['field 1', 'field 2', 'wobble', 'a,b,c'],
        ['another field 1', 'more field 2', 'wibble', 'c,b,a']]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(data)


$ cat test.csv
field 1,field 2,wobble,"a,b,c"
another field 1,more field 2,wibble,"c,b,a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the cvs.writer documentation:

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

and pass a proper 'quotechar' to the constructor in order to support proper quoting

or you replace the related chars inside your application while generating the CSV (outside the scope of the csv writer).

Comment: Thanks for the cite. Didn't know about that writer!